# Microsoft Kerberos vs. MIT kerberos

Tags: kerberos

Hey :) I’m learning about Kerberos. I first read about the MIT Kerberos and  then about the uses in Microsoft. I found some difference. I just want to be sure. Is it right that in the original MIT Kerberos a hash of the password never send from the client to the server, but in Microsoft Kerberos it happened?

Answer (score 0):

Huh?

Kerberos is Kerberos. It's a well defined specification and all the different implementations are more or less implemented the same. The Windows implementation certainly has it's share of quirks, but it doesn't in any way send the password hash to the server.

Kerberos uses a key agreement process to exchange messages. Both the client and KDC know the users "long term credential" which is their password hashed using a specific key derivation function. When the client wants to send a message to the KDC, it encrypts it using the long term credential. The KDC knows that credential so it can decrypt it. The response is encrypted in the same way.

Neither party sends the password or its hash to the other in general use.

There are two separate but specific scenarios where this doesn't apply however.

When using a certificate to logon via PKINIT, Windows will include the long term credential in the [user PAC of the ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-pac/2f9cae55-350a-423e-a692-1d16659e544a) (so the workstation can decrypt it), encrypted to the Diffie-Hellman derived secret.

The other scenario is when doing FIDO logon, the long term credential is included in an [authorization data element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/MS-KILE/732211ae-4891-40d3-b2b6-85ebd6f5ffff).

Both of these scenarios exist to allow clients to support legacy protocols that only understand password authentication.